# Deploy a simple static file server on Android Device

Tags: android

Is there a way to deploy a simple static file server to my app's sandbox folder on Android Devices.
I think it would be nice if it is as simple as `python3 -m http.server 8080`.
Any body has an idea about this?
Long for any replies.

```
                                           .
```

Comment: If the app has the debug flag you can browser the app private file-system in Android Studio  "Device File Explorer" https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/device-file-explorer

Comment: @Robert Wow, that's cool. It can be an alternative plan.